# Is there a way to determine what version of Intellij IDEA was used to create a project?

Tags: intellij-idea

My current workplace has given me access to a license for IntelliJ Ultimate to use while working remotely. They also have a clause in my employment that they own anything created on company time and/or using company resources. I am planning on making on using IntelliJ free version for side gigs, and was wondering if there was anything that could distinguish whether or not I was using the premium version for personal projects?

Comment: Are you going to build this on your work or personal computer?

Comment: @NicholasMartinez On my personal computer, which has the licensed and free version on it.

Comment: I should have been more specific. Are you going to be building this on the same machine you use for work?

Comment: Yes. To be specific this is my personal laptop, that I can use to access work resources and work remotely if need be. I use a desktop at work that I can remote into (but obviously wouldn't build my personal project on), and can access my laptop at work at the same time. The license I have is a floating license that I log in to, but can only use one at a given time (either desktop or laptop but not simultaneously.)

Comment: I would request a laptop from work. If they want to own property you create with their resources, you shouldn't be using your resources for their work. If will avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any features that are available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (e.g. the Spring framework integration or node.js support), and those features store configuration in the project files (in the form of facets, run configurations etc.), then yes, it will be possible to determine that you used IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate by inspecting your project files. If you only use the set of features available in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, it will not be possible to determine which version you used.

In any case, IntelliJ IDEA never stores any information in project files that can be used to identify which specific license it runs with (the one provided by your employer or one you acquired independently).